# JS weather description

Tags: javascript

В настоящее время разбираюсь с [заданием](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/show-the-local-weather).

В качестве источника текущей информации о погоде - объект, получаемый из:

```
https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lon=:longitude&lat=:latitude
```

Он содержит ссылку на *icons*, которые мне не нравятся (планирую нарисовать свои).

Где можно найти все возможные значения описания состояния погоды (например, `description: broken clouds`), чтобы знать, под что рисовать иконки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, можете попробовать это на [`node.js`](https://nodejs.org/) на ночь запустить:

```js
"use strict";
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

const descriptions = new Set();
const icons = new Set();

(async function main(){
  for(let x = -180; x <= 180; x++){
    for(let y = -90; y <= 90; y++){
      await addData(`https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=${x}&lon=${y}`);
    }
  }

  fs.writeFile(`./descriptions`, [...descriptions].join('\n'), err => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    else return console.log(`descriptions was saved!`);
  });

  fs.writeFile(`./icons`, [...icons].join('\n'), err => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    else return console.log(`icons was saved!`);
  });
})();

function addData(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      request({url, method: 'GET'}, (err, useless, body) => {
        JSON.parse(body).weather.forEach(el => {
          descriptions.add(el.description);
          icons.add(el.icon);
        });

        resolve();
      });
    } catch (e){
      reject();
    }
  });
}
```

:D
С учетом специфики того, что парсится (а именно - погода), на ночь это стоит запускать на протяжении пары недель.

Comment: Спасибо! =) Ради интереса запущу